# Connecting blocks together but prevent intersection

Tags: actionscript-3

**EDIT I have had a rethink:** I am going to use a much easier to implement tree structure with a grid so that each block can have up to 4 neighbours.

[image: Several blocks with a blue one for the mouse]

[image: Block 'inside' stalk]

I am trying to attach blocks on to the stalk (series of blocks) of this flower. Green blocks are the existing stalk and the blue block is the one attached to the mouse.

The block attached to the mouse will correctly snap to the nearest edges (I'm allowing diagonals for now) however the blocks will also be able to go 'inside' the stalk (image 2) by snapping to a block above or below.

My question is, how can I stop this? I considered

- Iterating the list again but ignoring the block I just tried to attach to; I think this will just result in the same problem really by attaching to another block 'inside' the stalk.
- Find which block I am intersecting and get another connection point from it, repeat until there are no intersections; This seems the better option but could be very messy when intersecting more than 1 block at a time

I should note that I plan on having a smoother snap, not just arbitrarily to an edge, so a grid is pretty much out of the question. I am pretty confident there must be an elegant solution, I'm just not seeing it!

Here is my snapping code as it currently stands

```
var mousePos:Point = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);// new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY);
var nearestPoint:Point = null;
var nearestDistance:Number = 0;

for (var i:int = 0; i < mPlant.length; ++i) {
    var part:PlantPart = mPlant[i];

    if (part is Stalk) {
        var connectionPoint:Point = (part as Stalk).getNearestConnectionPoint(mousePos);            
        var distance:Number = Point.distance(mousePos, connectionPoint);

        if (nearestPoint == null || distance < nearestDistance) {
            nearestPoint = connectionPoint;
            nearestDistance = distance;
        }
    }
}

if (nearestPoint != null) {
    mMousePointer.x = nearestPoint.x;
    mMousePointer.y = nearestPoint.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always pre-calculate a bounding Rectangle for the stalk, and then do the snapping check against that Rectangle.

The Rectangle can be calculated using something like this (un-tested code, though)

```
var _bounding:Rectangle = new Rectangle(int.MAX_VALUE, int.MAX_VALUE,0,0);
for each( var part:PlantPart in mPlant)
{
    if(part is Stalk)
    {
        _bounding.width    = part.width;    // Width will always be the same
        _bounding.height   = Math.max( _bounding.height, part.y );
        _bounding.x        = Math.min( _bounding.x, part.x );
        _bounding.y        = Math.min( _bounding.y, part.y );
    }
}
```

Comment: But as soon as you attached a block to the side, it would mess up the rectangle as it will have blank spaces. Sorry if that wasn't clear, but I want to be able to grow in any direction

Comment: I understand. Maybe you could create a tree of some sorts? Store each connected Stalk part as a child of another Stalk, and then you can use that to find the last (top-most) part of the entire stalk.
So each Stalk has a property
    private var _children:Vector.<Stalk>;
Create your Stalk with the bottom part first, then adding children to it;
    {2}
    {1}{3}
    {0}
Stalk {0} has a child, {1}, and it has two children, {2} and {3}. Since neither {2} or {3} has children, you know they're "top"most Stalk parts?

I don't know if this is a viable solution, I'm just thinking out loud here.

Comment: I was actually having a rethink of strategy because I will need to be able to find the 'tips' and for general pathfinding.
I basically thought the same thing!

I think I am going to go with a grid system and the tree structure as you described. it is a plant afterall :P